# Calculate statistics on slices of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randn(10),
                  'B': np.concatenate((np.repeat(np.nan, 4), np.array([0.7]), np.repeat(np.nan, 4), np.array([0.5]))),
                  'C': np.random.randn(10),
                  'D': np.concatenate((np.repeat(np.nan, 4), np.array([0.2]), np.repeat(np.nan, 4), np.array([0.15])))})
```

that looks something like this:

```
    A           B    C           D
0   0.537109    NaN  -0.204046   NaN
1   0.744488    NaN   0.903607   NaN
2   0.640995    NaN   0.712210   NaN
3   0.212758    NaN   0.293984   NaN
4  -1.786725    0.7   0.282747   0.20
5   1.486037    NaN  -0.199659   NaN
6   0.267356    NaN   0.890397   NaN
7   0.697408    NaN  -0.771626   NaN
8   0.044247    NaN  -1.157836   NaN
9   0.345658    0.5   1.556390   0.15
```

I would like to calculate some statistics such as mean on slices of this dataframe, for example, I would like the result to look something like:

```
    MeanA   B    MeanC  D
0   2.1     0.7  1.3    0.20
1   1.4     0.5  5.6    0.15
```

It other words, I want to keep the non-NA values from columns B and D and calculate the mean and others of A and C of the values above/below the non-NA values from B and D (in this case, let's include -1.786725 in both means, similarly for 0.282747).

NOTE: The values from MeanA and MeanC are made up because of the use of np.random.randn().

Now of course, my real dataframe contains more columns and more rows, so it would be nice to generalise this.

Comment: is B has a value in a particular row, is D also guaranteed to have a value in the same row?

Comment: @Simon: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: What exact values do you want to be included in the mean calculation? How far above/below the non-NA values would you go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
b_nans = df[~df.B.isnull()].index.values
cols_stats = ['A','C']
cols_nans = ['B','D']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = [['mean_'+ col for col in cols] + cols_nans])

for col_stat, col_nan in zip(cols_stats, cols_nans):
    df2[col_nan] = df[~df[col_nan].isnull()][col_nan].reset_index(drop=True)
    i_prev = 0
    for k,i in enumerate(b_nans):
        df2.loc[k, 'mean_'+ col_stat] = df.loc[i_prev:i,col_stat].mean()
        i_prev = i

print(df2)

      mean_A    mean_C       B    D
0   -0.059588   0.367446    0.7 0.20
1   0.037202    0.373243    0.5 0.15
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to manually work with the index.
Lets get the indices of the non-NaN rows, e.g. by

```
ind = np.array(df.dropna().index)
```

Now that you know the indices you can manually perform the operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach the problem with below steps:

1. Find out the index where you encounter 1st non-Nan value by following code:

   `index = df['B'].first_valid_index()` ## This will return 4
2. Now slice df with these index value

   `subset_df = df.iloc[0:index+1:,]`
3. take mean of the subset df for all the columns

   `upper_half_mean = subset_df .mean(axis=0)`

Do the steps 2 & 3 for the below part of the df and then just concat.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty simple way. The idea is to find the rows (index) where every column contains a value (the breakpoints). Iterate over those breakpoints and use those indices to get a sub slice of the dataframe. Calculate the mean for each column in that slice, which will return a single series for that slice. Then just concatenate those slices (series) together

```
np.random.seed(123)
# generate random data same way as in your question

# get indices of the breakpoints
idx = df[-df.isnull().any(axis=1)].index
idx = np.insert(idx, 0, 0)  # idx will be [0, 4, 9]

# calculate mean across columns for each slice of the dataframe
# this creates a list of pandas series
slices = []

for i in range(len(idx)-1):
    slices.append(df[idx[i]:idx[i+1]+1].mean())

# concat the separate series together as rows
output = pd.concat(slices, axis=1).T

# this is needed to get the correct values of the nan columns
output[['B', 'D']] = df[['B', 'D']].dropna().values
```

Which gives:

```
          A    B         C     D
0 -0.378040  0.7 -0.073018  0.20
1 -0.230593  0.5  0.817437  0.15
```